# BufferedWriter with no UTF-8 support

Tags: java, utf-8, io, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to make BufferedWriter write into txt file in format "latin - cyrillyc",and cyrillyc part is not working(hieroglyphs instead of text),neither do special symbols like ą ł ó ę etc.

FileWriter:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\ouzhi\\OneDrive\\Документы\\cardsLibrary\\input.txt",true);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(file);
while (true) {
System.out.print("Import a line to write: ");
String userInput = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
if(userInput.equals("stop")){
break;
}
String[] words = userInput.split(" ");
if(words.length >= 3 || words.length == 1){
System.out.println("Please,enter two words");
continue;
}
else{
writer.write(userInput);
writer.newLine();
writer.flush();
}
```

BufferedReader:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
            (new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\ouzhi\\OneDrive\\Документы\\cardsLibrary\\input.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: At a guess, UTF-8 is correct, and the reader you're using to check if it was done correctly is wrong.

Comment: You're using `FileWriter#<init>(String,boolean)`, which uses the default charset. Prior to Java 18 that was typically determined by the underlying platform. As of Java 18 the default charset is UTF-8. Unless, in either case, you've configured the default charset to be something else. Regardless, you're manually specifying `UTF_8` for both the scanner and the reader, so you should [do the same when creating the `FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.nio.charset.Charset,boolean)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding "Cp866" to scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in,"Cp866")
```